# Create a new pandas dataframe out of two existing dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I have two existing dataframes `df_A` and `df_B` with columns `X` and `Y`:

```
df_A

X Y
abc def
ghi jkl

df_B

X Y
mno pqr
stu vwx
zya bcd
```

I now want to create a new dataframe `df_new` which contains the columns `name` and `length`, where `length` is length of `df_A` and `df_B`. It should look like this one.

```
name length
A 2
B 3
```

How could I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to do this, varying in the level of automation and abstraction. Here is a rather manual way:

```py
df_new = pd.DataFrame({
    'name': ['A', 'B'],
    'length': map(len, [df_A, df_B])
})
```